# Mysql foreign key check taking too much time

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
    *
FROM products
WHERE products.deleted_at is null
    AND products.section_id = '1'
    AND products.status = '2'
ORDER BY products.created_at DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Time: 3 seconds

```
SELECT
    *
FROM products
WHERE products.deleted_at is null
    AND products.status = '2'
ORDER BY products.created_at DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Time:0.2 seconds

Why this foreign key check (`where section_id='1'`) is taking too much of time?
`section_id` refers to `id` of sections table.
The table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bishal`.`products` (
  ......
  `section_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  ......
  `status` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
  ......
  `deleted_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  ......
  INDEX `products_section_id_index` (`section_id` ASC),
  ......
  CONSTRAINT `products_section_id_foreign`
    FOREIGN KEY (`section_id`)
    REFERENCES `bishal`.`sections` (`id`),
  ......
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 225532
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Is it actually indexed in MySQL as a foreign key? If not, you probably need to add an index that column.

Comment: Are you sure u are using the correct datatypes? `'1'` and `'2'` are strings not integers

Comment: You probably have an index on `(deleted_at ,status,)` maybe even `created at` which covers the WHERE in the second query and not the first one.It has to table scan for section_id.For more show your table definition and the cardinality(the unique values in those columns)

Comment: @STLMikey Yes, it is indexed as foreign key.

Comment: @DarkBee `section_id` is `unsigned int not null`

Comment: Then u should do `WHERE section_id = 1` and not `'1'` :-)
How many records does your table has?

Comment: @Mihai I have not indexed those fields (`deleted_at` ,`status`, `created_at`)

Comment: @DarkBee No difference, 3s again. 200k rows on products

Comment: MySQL will implicitly cast, so `'1'` vs `1` will only make slight difference while evaluating query.

Comment: @MarcusAdams could be OP had varchar for his integers as well though. Without table dump we aren't certain

Comment: @Mihai The schema for required fields are provided on the question(updated) above.